# SQL to group time series meeting a criteria, according to start and end time

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am analyzing power systems time series data, and I am trying to find the contiguous data points that meet a certain boolean flag.

I would like to query this table by returning the start and end time corresponding to the inflection points wherein the value changed from 1 to 0, and 0 to 1.

How should go about implementing the pseudo-sql code below?

```
SELECT Time
FROM InputTable
WHERE InputTable.Value = 1
INTO OutputTable??, TimeStart??, TimeEnd??;
```

Input:

```
+-------+---------+------+
| Index |  Time   | Value|
+-------+---------+------+
|     0 | 00:00:01|   1  |
|     1 | 00:00:02|   1  |
|     2 | 00:00:03|   1  |
|     3 | 00:00:04|   0  |
|     4 | 00:00:05|   1  |
|     5 | 00:00:06|   1  |
|     6 | 00:00:07|   0  |
|     7 | 00:00:08|   1  |
+-------+---------+------+
```

Output:

```
+-------+-----------+----------+
| Index | TimeStart | TimeEnd  |
+-------+-----------+----------+
|     0 | 00:00:01  | 00:00:03 |
|     1 | 00:00:05  | 00:00:06 |
|     2 | 00:00:08  | 00:00:08 |
+-------+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the values based on adjacent "1"s.  This is tricky in MS Access.  One method that can be used in Access is to count the number of "0"s (or non-"1" values) before each row.

```
select ind, min(time), max(time)
from (select t.*,
             (select 1 + count(*)
              from inputtable as t2
              where t2.value = 0 and t2.time < t.time
             ) as ind
      from inputtable as t
     ) as t
where value = 1
group by ind
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the idea, now I finally get the intuition behind group by and sub-queries by analyzing how your sample code works. (Just checked out your book, great reviews! Definitely gonna get a copy.)